# How to parse JSON array which has Objects inside in Swift

Tags: arrays, json, swift, parsing, nested

I have a JSON response which seems to consist of multiple Objects where I fail to parse them and getting nil all the time when I try to access the fields inside the objects.

How can I parse for example the field name of the object which is inside "result"?

The JSON object:

```
{
result =     (
            {
        "cor_date" = "2016-01-04";
        "cor_id" = 24003;
        "course_type" = C;
        duration = 52;
        name = "Combined Course";
        "sco_id" = 24;
        status = ACT;
    },
            {
        "cor_date" = "2016-01-04";
        "cor_id" = 24002;
        "course_type" = C;
        duration = 52;
        name = "Intensive Course";
        "sco_id" = 24;
        status = ACT;
    }
);
}
```

I tried with this code here to parse the above JSON response and access the single fields:

```
let response = responseObject as? [String:AnyObject] //this works here
    print("response")
    print(response) 
    let resp2 = response!["result"]  as? [String:AnyObject]  // this results in nil
    print("resp2")
    print(resp2)

    if let response = responseObject as? [String:AnyObject] {
        if let result = response["result"] as? [String:AnyObject] {
            // work with the content of "result", for example:
            if let displayName = result["name"] {
                print("print display name of course")
                print(displayName)
            }
        } else {
            // handle the failure to decode
        }
    }
```

and I got the following repsones from the print command in the console:

```
response
Optional(["result": <__NSCFArray 0x7f9db0c86790>(
{
"cor_date" = "2016-01-04";
"cor_id" = 24003;
"course_type" = C;
duration = 52;
name = "Combined Course";
"sco_id" = 24;
status = ACT;
},
{
"cor_date" = "2016-01-04";
"cor_id" = 24002;
"course_type" = C;
duration = 52;
name = "Intensive Course";
"sco_id" = 24;
status = ACT;
}
)
])


resp2
nil
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This code does it:

```
//parse down the first layer of array
     let response = responseObject as? [String:AnyObject]
    print("response")
    print(response)

    //parse down the second layer of JSON object
    if let result = response!["result"]  as? [AnyObject] {

            // work with the content of "result", for example:
            if let displayName = result[0] as? [String:AnyObject]{
                print(displayName)

                let courseName = displayName["name"]
                print("courseName")
                print(courseName)
        }
```